# How to apply different styles to options of select tag in HTML

Tags: html, select

I am trying to apply some CSS class on the options of a drop down. The CSS apply correctly in Firefox, but in IE (7, 8) only color is getting applied. Can any body tell me how to apply styles on options of drop down for IE 7 and IE 8.

```
 .regionOption {
    font-weight: bold; 
 }

 .countryOption {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left:5px;
 }
```

I am using these CSS classes on options depending upon conditions. They work fine in Firefox.

I want to show difference between Region and country, is there any other way?

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: If you give some more information people can respond. There are ways to do this. Why don't you give us your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not currently support the full range of styles on option elements.

The full list of supported styles appears on the following MSDN article under the section titled "Styles":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28VS.85%29.aspx