# html select tag to apply css

Tags: html, css

I would like to apply a css file after choosing an option from a html `<select>` tag.

I tried to use these links to existing css files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="first.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="second.css" />
```

How can I use them in `<select>`?

```
    <select name="choose-an-option">
        <option value="first">
                            <!--use first.css here-->
        </option>
        <option value="second">
                            <!--use second.css here-->
        </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090867/how-to-apply-different-styles-to-options-of-select-tag-in-html

Comment: You're going to need to use javascript to do this.

Comment: @yAnTar my goal is not styling the options, i want to select different css files and apply them after choosing one from the dropdown menu

Comment: As @JeremyHolovacs said: you have to use ECMAScript

Comment: Also [Change CSS classes with javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#choose-an-option").change(function() {
    $("link").attr("href", this.value + ".css");
)};
```